# Grafana Dashboard wirh InfluxDB data and MSSQL data using same datasource variable

Tags: grafana

I am looking to find a way to have one variable that is used by Grafana to access 2 data sources. I am passing a server name that will collect data from InfluxDB and same server data from a MSSQL source server. I have been trying to create a daisy chain variable but have not had any success in doing so. Any one can provide some guidance on how to link a query variable and a data source variable so that data is returned from those sources.

Comment: You don't appear to be asking a specific question here. [so] isn't a "guidance" site, it's for asking specific programming questions. Can you elaborate on where, specifically, you're stuck? What about what you've tried isn't working? What about the articles/tutorials/documentation you've read didn't you understand?

Comment: I agree with your statements except this is all in a UI there is no code per-say. I tried to be as specific as possible as to what my goal is but the grafana builds variables on a form.

Comment: I didn't ask for code, I asked you to be specific in where you're stuck.

Comment: I can only assume this question has nothing to do with either sql-server of influxdb, but in fact is about variable management in grafana. But it is unclear what do you want to achieve with said variable(variables?) and what is you exact problem.

Comment: I am stuck where I state this line: "I have been trying to create a daisy chain variable but have not had any success in doing so" I have not been able to daisy chain these two types of variables.

Comment: @Markalex I need to pull data from both SQL and InFluxDB and I want one variable that specifies the server in which to return data for. For Influx its of type query and MSSQL its of type Data source.